# How to get JSCh/JCE to work with Java 1.4?

Tags: java, jsch, jce

According to http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/, `JSch is in pure Java, but it depends on Java Cryptography Extension (JCE). JSch has been known to work with J2SE 1.4.0 or later (no additional libraries required).`

Before anyone suggests I upgrade (which would indeed make my life easier), it is not an option: I have to get this working under Java 1.4.2.

So, I downloaded the JSch 0.1.54 source (and the JZLib 1.1.3 source) and fixed a few minor problems here and there. The remaining stumbling block is JCE. Without it, the following classes (found under `java.security.interfaces` starting with Java 1.5) are missing:

```
Error:(40, 3) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ECFieldFp
  symbol:   class ECGenParameterSpec
  symbol:   class ECParameterSpec
  symbol:   class ECPoint
  symbol:   class ECPrivateKey
  symbol:   class ECPrivateKeySpec
  symbol:   class ECPublicKey
  symbol:   class ECPublicKeySpec
  symbol:   class EllipticCurve
```

Where is the JCE source or jar that will fill this need? The Bouncy Castle page (https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) seems to be part of the solution, but there is a bewildering choice of downloads for Java 1.4. I tried `lcrypto-jdk14-157` but it's incomplete against the above list: it supplies only `ECPoint` and `ECPrivateKey`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [change log](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ChangeLog), the support was added since version **0.1.52**. These classes are used in `com/jcraft/jsch/jce/KeyPairGenECDSA.java`, `KeyPairECDSA.java`, `ECDH.hava`, `SignatureECDSA.java` and other new files to support `ECDSA` key.

If you don't have to connect a server supported only `ECDSA` key.  A solution is downloading source code from [sourceforge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsch/files/jsch/0.1.51/), building the jar file using JDK 1.4.2. There is one compatible problem:

```
jsch-0.1.51/src/main/java/com/jcraft/jsch/Util.java:490: replace(char,char) in java.
lang.String cannot be applied to (java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
    str = str.replace("~", System.getProperty("user.home"));
```

All you have to is fixing this error.

Comment: If support was added with 0.1.51, why is it missing from 0.1.54?

Comment: `Version 0.1.54` also support `ECDSA` key... That's why you got error using JDK 1.4.x

Comment: Please explain, because as written your comment makes no sense. If JSch 0.1.54 supported ECDSA, there would be no error.

Comment: I made a mistake when I read the `ChangeLog` before. I just update the answer, please read it again. Thanks.

Comment: I already imported the 0.1.54 source and fixed a few minor problems like the `str.replace` one, as I said in my question. Saying "Version 0.1.54 also support ECDSA key... That's why you got error using JDK 1.4.x" makes no sense: if 0.1.54 supported ECDSA keys, the classes that provide this support (ECFieldFp through EllipticCurve) would not be MISSING. If 0.1.54 has some sort of dependency (on JCE,it seems), where can the source and/or jars that satisfy this dependency be found?

Comment: Those missing classes can be found in packages `java.security.interfaces` or `java.security.spec` of new JCE version. But upgrading JCE is quite risky. That's why I choose version `0.1.51`.

Comment: Nope, they cannot. The 1.4.2 `java.security.interfaces` only contain the following interfaces: `DSAKey, DSAKeyPairGenerator, DSAParams, DSAPrivateKey, DSAPublicKey, RSAKey, RSAMultiPrimePrivateCrtKey, RSAPrivateCrtKey, RSAPrivateKey, RSAPublicKey`. It's Java 1.5 that adds `ECKey, ECPrivateKey, ECPublicKey` to this set.